# How to get enum value by passing value into it?

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

I'm using `enums` for a first time this way in Kotlin. I have `enum` with states. I'm expecting some `Int` value from `JSONObject` and I wanna convert this value to `enum` or null by passing this value into `enum` class. But its not working according to error I got. Is this even possible to do with enums?

Example:

```
enum class AccountRequestState(val state: Int){
    PENDING(0x001),
    APPROVED(0x002),
    REJECTED(0x003),
    CANCELED(0x004)
}

private val state: AccountRequestState? = AccountRequestState(js.getInt("state"))
```

That means state will hold value `AccountRequestState.PENDING` for example and it should represent Int with value of `0x001`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a static function to find which enum corresponds to which int value:

```
enum class AccountRequestState(val state: Int){
    PENDING(0x001),
    APPROVED(0x002),
    REJECTED(0x003),
    CANCELED(0x004);

    companion object {
        fun fromStateInt(state: Int): AccountRequestState? = values().firstOrNull { it.state == state }
    }
}
```

And then you can access it like this:

```
private val state: AccountRequestState? = AccountRequestState.fromStateInt(0x001)
```